# Unable to Find Tango Developer Apps on Tango Tablet

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I recently got a Tango tablet from a friend and changed the Google account from his to mine. He hadn't used it in a while, so I updated the system software and applications and everything is fully up to date. I'm having two problems which might be related:

1. I can't find any Tango Developer apps in the Play Store. For example, I can find "Tango Core" and "Constructor Developer Tool" while on my computer, but when I search for them on the tablet, they don't show up. Is this an issue with my google account?
2. When I try to open the "Project Tango Constructor" application that's already installed on the tablet, I get an error that reads "Library Mismatch. Update your Tango Service to the latest version." The Project Tango Constructor's app version is 1.1 and the Tango service version reads 0.

Thanks for any help or advice you can provide.

Comment: 1. There is an app called 'App Discovery'. Check there for Tango apps. 2. My 'Project Tango Constructor' is at 1.2.2 with a Tango Service Version reading like 1.50.2017.01.30-eisa-release ...some hex string... :stable . Did you do a factory reset when you switched from your friend to yourself?

Comment: Also note that the tablet is at end of life: https://plus.google.com/+ProjectTango/posts/RzK7Ey5V56Y

Comment: Ahh, I think the problem is that the tablet is unsupported. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I am testing the Tango tablet right now and I can confirm that the developpers tools tab is completely empty.

With the rise of Arcore I think that Tango is clearly not the focus for Google anymore.